# Not able to use UI/UX android libraries e.g. AndroidBootstrap and other

Tags: android

I am trying to work on UI of my first android project. Since the widgets in android studio are not so attractive, i have downloaded libraries from github. e.g. Android Bootstrap and others.

As mentioned in the github page, i made the following changes:

added to build.gradle (module:app)

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:+'
}
```

and added the following in my layout file:

```
xmlns:bootstrap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

But when i do the following:

```
<!-- basic button -->
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:text="Success"
bootstrap:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
bootstrap:bb_type="success"
/>
```

I get simple button rather than getting Bootstrap button. Am i missing something while using UI/UX libraries?
Similar scenario happens with font-awesome-text and all other libraries.

Please help.

Adding full xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bootstrap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap"
    xmlns:fontawesometext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Sized Buttons" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Large"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-rocket"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="large"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="primary" />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="default"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-twitch"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="default"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="primary" />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Small"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-puzzle-piece"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="small"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="primary" />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="xsmall"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-ticket"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="xsmall"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="primary" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.FontAwesomeText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fontawesometext:fa_icon="fa-github"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        />


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </HorizontalScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete xml file?

Comment: I have added the complete xml in the question..pls check